# Why pursue not stopping after the first message output?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My code is

```
 CPL> (top-level
       (pursue
         (format t "First~%")
           (format t "Third~%")
           (format t "Second~%"))
             )
 
 First
 Third
 Second
 NIL
 CPL>
```

Why answer is not just 'First'?

Because [cram tutorials doc](http://www.ros.org/wiki/cram_pl/Tutorials/SetupAndFirstSteps) says : 'Only the first form is executed. The other forms are evaporated.'

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11231/why-pursue-not-stopping-after-the-first-message-output?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2011-09-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your code is slightly different from that one of the tutorial. The tutorial says:

```
(top-level
  (pursue
    (format t "First~%")
    (seq
      (sleep 2)
      (format t "Third~%"))
    (seq
      (sleep 1)
      (format t "Second~%"))))
```

Please note the sleeps. What happens in your case is that all three forms terminate very quickly and pursue doesn't have a chance to evaporate any of the tasks. With the sleeps, you force `Third` and `Second` to take long enough to be evaporated.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2011-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0